# Can you add multiple batting averages to formulate the chances a team gets a hit in an inning?

Tags: probability

Say you have 3 batters due up in an inning of a baseball game, all with .333 averages.  I know the probability that they get one hit out of the bunch is not 100% (which adding up their averages would be).  However, I'm having a brain fart and can't reason why it wouldn't be.  The way I see it, you have a 33% x 3 so it's 90%.

Can someone show me how to calculate the odds of getting a hit in an inning given averages a, b, and c?

Thanks.

Comment: You can add probabilities for mutually exclusive events, but that is not the case here.  Imagine $3$ batters with $.350$: your method might produce an impossible probability greater than $1$.  On the other hand the expected number of hits in your example is indeed $0.999$

Answer (score 1):

Common trick when you want at find the probability of at least one event happening is to find the probability of all events not happening and then subtract it from one. So you have:

$$P = 1 - P(\bar{A},\bar{B},\bar{C}) = 1-(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)$$

On the other hand to find the number of expected hits by these 3 batters you need to calculate:

$$E[X] = 3abc + 2\sum_{cyc}(1-a)bc + \sum_{cyc}(1-a)(1-b)c = a+b+c$$

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it had to be something like that; being five years separated from math courses doesn't help when trying to remember stuff like this.

Comment: If $a, b, c$ are very small then you have $P \approx a + b + c$.  For example if $a = 0.01, b = 0.02, c = 0.03$ then $P = 0.058906$.  The reason for this is that the expected number of hits is exactly $a + b + c$, and two or more hits is exceedingly rare when $a, b, c$ are small.  But in the baseball case $a, b, c$ are large enough (in the range $0.2$ to $0.4$, roughly) that you can't make that simplification.